# Re-creating a section style in LaTeX book

Tags: sectioning, titles, titlesec, books, book-design

How does one go about recreating the following section style in LaTeX, so that the section title begins before the main body of the text and horizontal lines are drawn above and below it? Would the titlesec package be most appropriate? If someone could produce a code to give the desired effect, I'd be very grateful. I'm working in the 'book' class, but, unfortunately, I have no idea where to start working on the code.

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at the titlesec package? https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf

Comment: Which margins do you want to have?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but ... what about `\documentclass{memoir}\chapterstyle{verville}
\begin{document}\chapter{foo}\end{document}` ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've been working in book, so a solution in that documentclass would be appreciated. It would be far too messy to switch to memoir, given the amount of work I've done so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: I add Plan B (pure marginal) and C (margin runin) according to your comment. Solution B is achieved by the `leftmargin` format of `titlesec` package, while solution C is by `\hspace` since I didn't come up with an elegant way to do it.

---

I am not sure if I understand your figure correctly, so I provide a solution based on your verbal description. Here is an answer with the support of `\titlerule` command from the `titlesec` package that can draw lines around the title.

- The `\titleformat` command controls the heading format. In the following MWE, it draw two lines of 2pt width above and under the section title. The spacing between the upper line and the title is enlarged by 0.8 ex and that between the lower one and title by 0.4 ex. The horizontal space between the label (i.e. "1.1") and the title is 0.5 em.
- The `\titlespacing` command adjusts the spacing around the title. It sets zero distance between the section label to the left margin, and around 4 ex (with stretchability) to both vertical before- and after-skip of the title.

For more details, please read the `titlesec` package manual.

Here is the MWE. It is tested under PdfLaTeX.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2in}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a chapter}

% --- Plan A ---
\titleformat{\section}[block]
    {\titlerule[2pt]\addvspace{0.8ex}%
    \bfseries\Large}
    {\thesection}{0.5em}
    {}[{\addvspace{0.4ex}\titlerule[2pt]}]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*4}{*4}

\section{A customized section heading}

bla bla bla.

bla bla bla bla.

% --- Plan B: A pure marginal section title ---
\newcommand{\marginbelowline}[1]{%
    #1\par%
    \noindent\hfill\rule{\titlewidth}{2pt}%
}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
    {\filleft\large
    \setlength{\titlewidth}{\oddsidemargin}%
    \addtolength{\titlewidth}{-\marginparsep}
    \setlength{\titlewidth}{0.95\titlewidth}
    \titleline*[l]{\titlerule[2pt]}%
    \addvspace{6pt}%
    \normalfont\sffamily}
    {\thesection}{1em}{\marginbelowline}
\titlespacing{\section}{5pc}{*2}{*2}

\section{Plan B. Pure marginal section title}

Plan B: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

bla bla bla

You need to add paragraphs here to ensure that the section title won't overlap in the left margin.

Probably there will be better way to achieve this.

Let's talk about Plan C.

% --- Plan C: A section title that starts from the left margin and runs into the text body ---

\newlength{\marginrule}
\setlength{\marginrule}{\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength{\marginrule}{-\marginparsep}
\setlength{\marginrule}{0.95\marginrule}

\newcommand{\marginruninto}[1]{%
    #1\par%
    \noindent\hspace{-\oddsidemargin}\rule{\marginrule}{2pt}%
}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
    {\bfseries\Large}
    {\hspace{-\oddsidemargin}\rule{\marginrule}{2pt}\\%
     \hspace*{-\oddsidemargin}\thesection}{0.5em}
    {\marginruninto}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*4}{*4}

\section{Plan C. An overflowed section title with a lot of words to check if it can linebreak correctly}

Plan C: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

Some paragraphs.

Another paragraph.

\end{document}
```

A screenshot of MWE:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. What I am actually looking for is a section heading that begins to the left of the 'A chapter' in your example, but also one where the horizontal lines end when the non-indented main body of the text ('A chapter' in your example) begins, as in my diagram.

Comment: @wrb98 I understand a little bit. Do you want to let the whole title stay in the left margin, or allow it to overflow into the main text body?

Comment: Yes, and the two horizontal lines to extend from the beginning of the section title to where the text begins (so not across the whole of the page)

Comment: @wrb98 Please check my edited answer. I am still not sure you are asking for solution B or C, so I just provide both.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's solution C!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what documentclass you are using (or any of your code) but as it seems from your showing of what you want your `\section` command to result in I assume that you are using a class that supports `\chapter`. --- GOM

The `memoir` class (a superset of the `book`, `report`, and `article` classes) does provide chapters. I think that the following does what you are after.

```
% secprob.tex SE 532078 Change \section format
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setsecindent{-2cm} % move into the margin
\newcommand{\ruledsec}[1]{%
  \hspace{-2cm}\hspace{-\parindent}\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}\\ % rule before title
  \Large\bfseries\raggedright #1 % the title
  \hspace{-2cm}\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}% rule after the title
}
\setsecheadstyle{\ruledsec}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]

And a bit more text for the next paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Change the lengths to suit your layout. Read the `memoir` documentation (`texdoc memoir`) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but I specified in the original post that I was working in 'book'

Comment: @wrb98 As I said in my answer `memoir` is a superset of the `book` class providing all the functionality of `book` with much more. If you don't want to change that is fine with me. Note that my answer gave the `\section` format that you asked for. --- GOM